# How to animate sprites on keypress on canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, sprite

How do I animate the character on keypress? I changed the sprite position which shows the next image, but how do I loop through the two images so that I can show the player running while the key is pressed.

I need the first and the second frame.

Keyevents:

```
if(keys[39]){
      //right arrow
      if (mario.velX < mario.speed){
        mario.velX++;

        if(!mario.jumping){
          //mario sprite position
          mario.frame = 0;
        }
      }
    }
```

And the draw function

```
this.frame = 0;

  var marioImg; //mario image

  var that = this;

  this.init = function() {
    marioSprite = new Image();
    marioSprite.src = 'images/mario-sprites.png';
  }

  this.draw = function(){
    that.sX = that.width * that.frame;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(marioSprite, that.sX, that.sY, that.width, that.height, that.x, that.y, that.width, that.height);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the two images into and array

```
var imageArray = []; // array to hold images
var img = new Image(); // create and load first image
img.src = "imageOne.png";
imageArray.push(img);  // put it in the array

img = new Image(); // same for image two
img.src = "imageTwo.png";
imageArray.push(img);
```

You will need some variables. One to control how long each image is displayed and another to hold which image is displayed. You can use the current time to keep it nice and even.

```
var millsecondsPerImage = 100;  // each frame is 100 ms 1/10th of a second

var currentTime = new Date().valueOf(); // get the time in milliseconds

// Divide current time by how long to display for. Round down with floor
// then modulo the length of the image array
var imageToDraw = imageArray[Math.floor(currentTime / millsecondsPerImage) % imageArraylength];

// draw the current image image
ctx.drawImage(imageToDraw, posx, posy);
```

That will cycle any number of images, how ever many you put in the array.